# Использование dependency property UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Не могу найти нормального примера по использованию Dependency property.
Вот я зарегистрировал свойство в классе helpers.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty FilterApplyProperty= DependencyProperty.Register("FilterApply", 
        typeof(ICommand),typeof(EffectListSelection),new PropertyMetadata(1,OnValuePropertyChanged));
```

Вот конструктор

```
public iCommand FilterValue
    {
        get { return (iCommand) GetValue(FilterApplyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterApplyProperty, value);}
    }
```

И сам метод

```
 private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        string listviewName = AssociatedObject.Name;
        temp = (e as ItemClickEventArgs).ClickedItem as FiltersViewModel;
        MainViewModel.Effect = temp.Type;

        this.EffectApply.Execute(this.temp.Type);  <---
    }
```

Разобрался. Просто нужно было вызвать команду и все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Просто нужно было вызвать команду и все работает

```
  this.EffectApply.Execute(this.temp.Type);
```

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, `DependencyProperty` нужны для того, чтобы работал `Binding`, анимации, стили и тому подобное. Обычно такое нужно для кастомных UI-элементов.

Работать с ними просто, точно так же, как и с обычными свойствами. Плюс вы можете снова-таки выставлять значение в стилях, например.

---

Мой хрустальный шар говорит, что вы пытаетесь из статического метода `OnValuePropertyChanged` обратиться к свойству или методу экземпляра. Это, разумеется, работать не будет. Но у вас есть экземпляр, переданный как параметр `d`, так что возможно вы хотите

```
EffectListSelection self = (EffectListSelection)d;
self.Command();
```

---

Если вы на деле пишете не UI-объект, возможно, имеет смысл пользоваться не `DependencyProperty`, а обыкновенными свойствами, реализовав `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

---

Кстати, у вас `DependencyProperty` определено неправильно. Вы не дали весь код, но даже в том куске, который вы привели, название свойства, которое вы регистрируете (`"FilterApply"`) не совпадает с реальным названием свойства (`FilterValue`). Ожидайте багов и неработающих фич. (Или объявите `DependencyProperty` правильно.)

Comment: EffectListSelection effectListSelection = (EffectListSelection) d;
effectListSelection.FilterApply = temp.Type;   Так я сделал, Теперь мне нужно выполнить команду, которая находится в другом классе без создания экземпляра. Через Binding

Comment: @SmiLe: А что у вас «команда»? Если это на самом деле метод, то вызвать метод без экземпляра класса не получится в принципе, `Binding` тут не поможет.

Comment: public ICommand FilterApply
        {
            get
            {
                return _applyCommand ?? (_applyCommand = new CommandHandler(() => ApplyEffectAsync(File), _canExecute));
            }
        }

Comment: @SmiLe: Если экземпляра нет — то не, не получится.